# H1:hover in full div

Tags: css, title, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have a **div** with a **h1**, that `h1:hover` is `color:#FFFFFF`.
What I want is when I mouse hover the **div** the **h1** turns `#FFFFFF`.

Is there any jquery to get **h1** hover to the full div?

url:http://www.isolacor.com/site/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS:

```
div:hover h1 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$('div').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('h1').css('color', '#fff');
});
```